# Collections Framework hierarchy: Why map never connected to collections?

Tags: collections, dictionary, frameworks

Why, within the collections hierarchy, does map not implement the collections interface like set, list and queue do?

e.g in this diagram:

[Collections hierarchy diagram](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=collections%20hierarchy%20in%20java&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=IOZvU5Z7ids51qmBgAE&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=667#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=QGuCfQSODMDLWM%253A;guupRXf5mrXH4M;http%253A%252F%252F2.bp.blogspot.com%252F-1a_tnw4c4Y4%252FUcdyD3nGbDI%252FAAAAAAAABbA%252Fm2HIaLcxoWU%252Fs1600%252Fcollections.jpg;http%253A%252F%252Fjlunaquiroga.blogspot.com%252F2013%252F06%252Fjava-collections-framework-part-1-intro.html;934;661)

Comment: This got answered already couple of times. I.e. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651819/why-doesnt-java-map-extends-collection

Answer (score 0):

Because unlike Lists and Sets, they're built on key-value pairs. The collection interface only has methods to interact with a unique object at a time, not a key-value pair.