# Why streams cannot be created for map in Java8?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

Why we can't create the **streams** for **map**?

Comment: Map does not implement Collection.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Streams cannot directly be created from maps because a map is not a collection. For further explanation on why a map is not a collection you can view this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2651833/2796463.

Maps in Java can be iterated in three ways:

1. A set of keys
2. A collection of values
3. A a set of key value pairs

You need to specify which order you wish to iterate through the map before creating a stream

1. `map.keySet().stream()`
2. `map.values().stream()`
3. `map.entrySet().stream()`

Comment: Good answer, but it would be even stronger if you in a concrete way answered the original question (_Why we can't create the streams for map?_).