# Spring Data: JPA repository findAll() to return *Map instead of List?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Data JPA repository interface that looks something like this:

```
@Repository
public interface DBReportRepository extends JpaRepository<TransactionModel, Long> {

    List<TransactionModel> findAll();
    List<TransactionModel> findByClientId(Long id);
}
```

Is there a workaround to make the same but for a Collection to be returned of type `HashMap<K, V>`? I've looked through the Spring Data classes and couldn't find anything other than List<> return values.

Comment: There isn't any, what's stopping you from doing it yourself?

Comment: @isah you mean create such a function for spring data myself?

Comment: Create such a function for yourself I mean, wherever you're calling this repository, after loading the list, you can map it to `Map` with a Java 8 one-liner.

Comment: @isah that is one possibility. I am not sure if it is good in terms of performance. Iteration takes time, especially when my `<List>` contains 10 000 - 100 000 `Transaction` objects. I have to match id's of two `<List>` with `Transaction` objects and was wondering if I can shave some time off by using `*Map` constructions when doing matching. But if I can only get a `<List>` and then convert it to `*Map` and then do the matching, I am not quite sure this will bring me any additional improvements in speed.

Comment: How would your sql look like to? What will be the key and whats the value?

Comment: @Patrick key would be the `id` and value = `Transaction` object

Comment: and `id` is the same `id` of its Transaction in value?

Comment: @Patrick yes that is true

Comment: can you provide more information in your question what you really want to do and how the map should look like. I think you will also use a map<Long, List<Transaction>>?

Comment: @Patrick map will look like this: `Map<Long, Transaction> transactionMap = new HashMap<Long, Transaction>();`

Comment: [Map is not a supported return type for Spring Data repository methods](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_supported_query_return_types) so @Patrick's answer below is the correct solution.

Comment: @DenissM.The iteration will result in linear time complexity, which you will get anyway, if you need to visit each item, so this is not a problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I dont think you will find an easier solution as to create a simple one liner to convert your result to a map. It is simple and fast with java 8 lambdas:

```
Map<Long, Transaction> transactionMap = transactionList.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Transaction::getId, Function.identity()));
```

Answer (score 40):

Just had to solve something similar and Patricks answer helped but it can be improved by indicating where to add it.

To to make it appear like the JPA repo returns a map, an improvement would to wrap this up in a default method in the repository interface. Saves you having to perform a stream in all the consuming classes.

```
@Repository
public interface DBReportRepository extends JpaRepository<TransactionModel, Long> {

    List<TransactionModel> findAll();

    default Map<Long, TransactionModel> findAllMap() {
        return findAll().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(TransactionModel::getId, v -> v));
    }

    List<TransactionModel> findByClientId(Long id);

    default Map<Long, TransactionModel> findByClientIdMap(Long id) {
        return findByClientId(id).stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(TransactionModel::getId, v -> v));
    }
}
```

Comment: While I think the method of using the stream to transform the list to a map is a straightforward and decent approach, it does not belong in the repository.  Repositories are for CRUD and finders.  The transformation is business logic; therefore, it belongs in service code, not in repository code.  As software developers, we need to practice proper separation of concerns.

Comment: Be that as it may, the OP asked how to make the JPA repo return a map instead of list. While it may be better architecture to wrap this in a middle layer, it answers the question

Comment: [Spring Data - Supported query return types](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#appendix.query.return.types)

Comment: [Latest link to Spring Data Query Return Types](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/repositories/query-return-types-reference.html#appendix.query.return.types)

Answer (score 0):

You could get your map from a custom streamable wrapper type which is documented in [Spring Data JPA reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/repositories/query-methods-details.html#repositories.collections-and-iterables).

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor(staticName = "of")
public class TransactionModels implements Streamable<TransactionModel> {
    
    private final Streamable<TransactionModel> streamable;

    @Override
    public Iterator<TransactionModel> iterator() {
        return streamable.iterator();
    }

    public Map<Long, TransactionModel> asMap() {
        return streamable.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Transaction::getId, Function.identity()));
    }
}
```

```java
@Repository
public interface DBReportRepository extends JpaRepository<TransactionModel, Long> {

    TransactionModels findAll();

    TransactionModels findByClientId(Long id);

}
```

The reason why you cannot get your desired `Map<Long, TransactionModel>` method in Spring Data is that `java.util.Map<K,V>` will be delegated to `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution` instead of `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution` by default. And it's reasonable becuase [`Map` is not extending from `Collection` in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651819/why-doesnt-java-map-extend-collection). But in your case you would like to use `Map` as a "collection". Fortunately you can [extend Spring Data repository with custom methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/repositories/custom-implementations.html#repositories.single-repository-behavior) which could return any type you like.

Answer (score -1):

Creating a map after having retrieved your entities is not a solution if you are trying to improve your performance. It will take longer to retrieve the whole entity and then add the selected fields into a map, than to directly retrieve a map, or a list.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33527497)

Answer (score -2):

Another Solution use java 8 lambdas:

Using a **groupingBy** method of Collectors that grouping transactionList by ID and storing results in a Map instance

```
Map<Long, Transaction> transactionMap = transactionList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(v->v.getId()));
```

Comment: How is that another solution? Even though this does not work, did you even test this?

Comment: sure, I tested it. but you couldn't implement a method to return a map directly in the repository. you need to implement the method in the repository class that return List then get this list and convert it to a map (using a above code)

Comment: No you did not test it. At least not the version you posted as the return type Map<Long, Transaction> isn't even correct.