# Spring Data: JPA repository return Map instead of List?

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have such Query where from which I want to extract movie title and its rating

```
   @Query(value ="SELECT m.title, avg(r.rating) " +
        "FROM movies m " +
        "INNER JOIN " +
        "ratings r " +
        "ON m.movieid = r.movieid " +
        "WHERE m.genres LIKE %:genre% " +
        "GROUP BY m.title " +
        "ORDER BY avg(r.rating) DESC " +
        "LIMIT 10",
        nativeQuery = true)
 List<Movies> topTenMoviesByGenreLikeIgnoreCase(@Param("genre") String genre);
```

But this list obviously cannot store the resultSet with 2 values

After learning about it I've found e.g. this link [Spring Data: JPA repository findAll() to return *Map instead of List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41876122/spring-data-jpa-repository-findall-to-return-map-instead-of-list) but their implementation seems unclear to me.

I don't understand where do they get the Long value from in the first link

```
default Map<Long, TransactionModel> findByClientIdMap(Long id) {
    return findByClientId(id).stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(TransactionModel::getId, v -> v));
}
```

How do I create my map?

```
default Map<Movies, Float> topTenMoviesByGenreLikeIgnoreCaseMap(@Param("genre") String genre) {
    return topTenMoviesByGenreLikeIgnoreCase(genre).stream().collect(Collectors.toMap());
}
```

---

Movies class:

```
@Entity
public class Movies {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer movieid;

private String title;
private String genres;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "movieid")
private Set<Ratings> rates = new HashSet<>();

public Movies() {
}

public Movies(String title, String genres) {
    this.title = title;
    this.genres = genres;
}

/*Getters and Setters for variables*/

public Set<Ratings> getRates() {
    return rates;
}

public void setRates(Set<Ratings> rates) {
    this.rates = rates;
}
}
```

---

Ratings class:

```
@Entity
public class Ratings {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer rateid;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "movieid")
private Movies movieid;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "userid")
private Usrs userid;

private float rating;
private Integer timestamp;

public Ratings() {
}

public Ratings(Movies movieid, Usrs userid, float rating, Integer timestamp)
{
    this.movieid = movieid;
    this.userid = userid;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
/*Getters and Setters for variables*/
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object[]` as a query result this way

```
@Query(value ="SELECT m.title, avg(r.rating) " +
        "FROM movies m " +
        "INNER JOIN " +
        "ratings r " +
        "ON m.movieid = r.movieid " +
        "WHERE m.genres LIKE %:genre% " +
        "GROUP BY m.title " +
        "ORDER BY avg(r.rating) DESC " +
        "LIMIT 10",
        nativeQuery = true)
 List<Object[]> topTenMoviesByGenreLikeIgnoreCase(@Param("genre") String genre);
```

So then

```
default Map<String, Float> topTenMoviesByGenreLikeIgnoreCaseMap(@Param("genre") String genre) {
    return topTenMoviesByGenreLikeIgnoreCase(genre)
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap((arr->arr[0].toString()), (arr->Float.valueOf(arr[1].toString()))));
}
```

As you can see `topTenMoviesByGenreLikeIgnoreCaseMap` returns `Map` where the movie title is the key. To make a `Movie` entity the key you should use a `JPQL` query instead of a native one.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I apriciate you notes about the query. It's really wierd written. I've added the Ratings class to the question. Would you mind to explain what is `JPQL` query and how to work with it in my case?
When I use your solution I get `Required type: Map<String,Float>
Provided:Map<Object,Object>`. Should it be changed to `Map<Object, Object>` and then casted to `String, Float`?

Comment: That's right. It is my fault. You have to cast types

Comment: `JPQL` is used to make queries against entities instead of database tables. `ORM` can generate `SQL` query based on `JPQL` query

Comment: To my surprise if I cast it like that `Collectors.toMap((arr-> (String)arr[0]),  (arr-> (Float)arr[1])))` I see **Casting 'arr[0]' to 'String' is redundant** and **Casting 'arr[1]' to 'Float' is redundant**. A little bit later I will try your solution and write back if it will work and accept your answer

Comment: I've edited your answer. It worked perfectly with such casting. Thanks for the help and noticing odd query aspects

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```
@Query(value ="SELECT m.title as title, r.avg(rating) as rates " +
    "FROM movies m " +
    "INNER JOIN " +
    "ratings r " +
    "ON m.movieid = r.movieid " +
    "WHERE m.genre = LIKE %:genre% " +
    "GROUP BY r.avg(rating) " +
    "ORDER BY r.avg(rating) DESC " +
    "LIMIT 10",
    nativeQuery = true)

List<Movies> topTenMoviesByGenreLikeIgnoreCase(@Param("genre") String genre);    



default Map<Movies, Set<Ratings>> topTenMoviesByGenreLikeIgnoreCaseMap(@Param("genre") String genre) {
    return topTenMoviesByGenreLikeIgnoreCase(genre).stream().collect(
                                                            Collectors.toMap(
                                                            tuple -> (tuple.getTitle(),
                                                            tuple -> (tuple.getRates())
                                                         ));
}
```

Comment: I apriciate your suggestion but it seems there are some minor mistakes. Odd dots like  `collect(.Collectors.toMap(.tuple`. Btw what is **tuple** and where did you get it from? Also, in my case tuple doesn't have method _get()_

Comment: `tuple` is defined as a row of the table produced by SELECT query.

Comment: I'm sorry but **tuple** still doesn't have _get()_ method. And I wonder why then. Moreover, why do you cast everything to String if you apply  `toString()` and `floatValue()`? I suppose to store Float as a value, I don't need to cast it to String

Comment: if we change it a little bit to `tuple -> (tuple.getTitle())` mb it's ok and we don't need cast to string anything but what about `tuple -> (tuple.get("ratings")).floatValue()`? Since the output is the Movies class I cant get a rating of a movie because it's stored in other class

Comment: Oops, i have missed it too.

Comment: If `tuple` is defined as a row of the table produced by SELECT query, I must have a table with 10 rows because of `LIMIT 10` and only 2 columns such as `m.title as title` and `r.avg(rating) as ratings` but, I guess, since it's stored in `List<Movies>` it saves only the Movies part and eventually I get only methods of the Movies class. How to deal with that? I cannot apply the same query just to this maps and hope it will understand by itself that the first output must be the key and the second one is the value

Comment: Can you please share your model class for `movies`

Comment: Sure, I'll attach the Movies class to my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227353/discussion-between-chandra-kant-and-63350541).