# Fetching 2 column records from database and store them in hashmap using JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

There is one table called City.
City tables has id, city_name, state_code and state_name.
I want to retrieve state_code and state_name. But don't want to use
"select c from City c". I just want those two column from the table.

Is it possible to use Hashmap in this situation? Or is there any other possible way?

I have tried using class based projection but there is only one use of that projection and no where else its being used. So I'm feeling that it will effect the performance in some way.

The catch is I want to avoid findAll().

```
@Query(select c.stateCode, c.stateName from City c)

//Here I want to try to return stateCode and stateName
```

Comment: Hello, with the query you will get a list of object arrays. List <Object []> You can iterate over the list and get stateCode from the array element 0 and stateName from the element 1.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this please?

```
@Repository
public interface CityRepository extends JpaRepository<City, Long> {

List<City> findAll();

default Map<String, String> findAllMap() {
    return findAll().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(City::getStateCode, City::getStateName));
   }
}
```

Reference from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51184124/10277150

Comment: The catch is I want to avoid findAll().
@Query(select c.stateCode, c.stateName from City c)
//Here I want to try to return stateCode and stateName