# Can I write a for loop that iterates over both collections and arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, collections

Is there a possibility to check if an object is either an array or a collection with one clause? What I am trying to achieve:

Assuming arrays implement Iterable, and assuming the Object `foo` could be either an array or a collection, I'd like to use a code snippet like this:

```
if (foo instanceof Iterable) {
  for (Object f : (Iterable) foo) {
    // do something with f
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, an array cannot be cast to Iterable. Nor does it implement Collection. Are there any other possibilities to handle both in one loop like the above? Instead of -- of course -- using an if-else if-clause and two loops (which wouldn't be nice).

Edit: In response to these answers. I am aware of the isArray() method but in this case the casting in

```
...
for (Object f : (Iterable) foo) {
...
```

will fail. That'd a pity and a code redundancy since I would have to use two loops although a foreach-loop works both with Collections and Arrays.

Comment: The way I see it, `foo` must be declared as `Object`. So you have to cast anyway. Are you trying to cast just once?

Comment: The foreach-loop won't work if I cast it to Object -- you cannot iterate through objects.

Comment: It's a good idea to avoid a design that leads to this in the first place. Even if you had a common interface for this to work with just one for-each loop, you'd still have many type casts. Your code wouldn't be type-safe (`Object[]`? raw `Iterable`?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The other answers are all trying hard to answer the original title question:

> Is there a common interface or superclass for arrays and collections?

But your real question is in the body:

> Are there any other possibilities to handle both in one loop like the above?

The answer is: **No, there's no way to write a single `for` loop that iterates over both collections and arrays.**

You could jump through a bunch of hoops to turn the arrays into lists, but you'll almost certainly end up with a bigger mess than if you just wrote two (or more) loops. Calling `getClass().isArray()` tells you what you have but you still can't work with it without some sort of cast. `Arrays.asList()` doesn't work for arrays of primitives.

Comment: Thank you for this response. It's a pity that you cannot abstract from Arrays/Collection and primitive/objects in Java, as the loop construction would remain the same and would make the code more readable. But I guess that's just the way it is and we have to live with it.

Answer (score 18):

**Regarding a condition to check if `foo` is either a collection or an array:**

[`Class#isAssignableFrom`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)) may come in handy.

```
Class<?> fooClass = foo.getClass();
boolean isArrayOrCollection = Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(fooClass) ||
                              Object[].class.isAssignableFrom(fooClass);
```

I reasonably assume you won't test it on primitive arrays since you have collections which work only with the wrapper classes.

I guess you can safely replace `Object[].class.isAssignableFrom(fooClass)` with `fooClass.isArray()`

```
boolean isArrayOrCollection = Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(fooClass) ||
                              fooClass.isArray();
```

and it would also work for a primitive array class.

---

I've run a small "test"

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Predicate<Class<?>> p = c -> Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(c) || 
                                     c.isArray();

        System.out.println(p.test(new int[0].getClass()));
        System.out.println(p.test(new Integer[0].getClass()));
        System.out.println(p.test(Collections.emptyList().getClass()));
        System.out.println(p.test(Collections.emptySet().getClass()));

        System.out.println(p.test(Collections.emptyMap().getClass()));
    }
}
```

which [results in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651819/why-doesnt-java-map-extends-collection)

```
true
true
true
true
false
```

---

**Regarding a generic loop that would run over both arrays and
   collections:**

You simply **can't** write an accurate construction to handle this: `Collection` (or `Iterable`) and `Object[]` have little in common (`Object` as a common parent and its methods are not enough).

I think it's sensible to build own abstraction which would treat collections and arrays in the same manner. Having no particular context, I can come up with a simple idea of two subclasses, each of which defining how its *source* (either a collection or an array) should be iterated. Then, programming to an interface will help to manage them equally.

A very simplified example would be:

```
interface Abstraction<T> {
    void iterate(Consumer<? super T> action);

    static <T> Abstraction<T> of(Collection<T> collection) {
        return new CollectionAbstraction<>(collection);
    }
    static <T> Abstraction<T> of(T[] array) {
        return new ArrayAbstraction<>(array);
    }
    static IntArrayAbstraction of(int[] array) {
        return new IntArrayAbstraction(array);
    }
}

class CollectionAbstraction<T> implements Abstraction<T> {
    Collection<T> source;

    public CollectionAbstraction(Collection<T> source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    @Override
    public void iterate(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        source.forEach(action);
    }
}

class ArrayAbstraction<T> implements Abstraction<T> {
    T[] source;

    public ArrayAbstraction(T[] source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    @Override
    public void iterate(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        for (T t : source) {
            action.accept(t);
        }
    }
}

class IntArrayAbstraction implements Abstraction<Integer> {
    int[] source;

    public IntArrayAbstraction(int[] source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    @Override
    public void iterate(Consumer<? super Integer> action) {
        for (int t : source) {
            action.accept(t);
        }
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Abstraction.of(new Integer[] {1, 2, 3}).iterate(System.out::println);
        Abstraction.of(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)).iterate(System.out::println);
        Abstraction.of(new int[] {1, 2, 3}).iterate(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

I believe the approach above is pretty versatile. You don't depend on how a certain source is iterated, you may selectively modify them.

Comment: Whereas this seems good practical advice for the OP, it does not directly respond to the actual question, which inquires about a common supertype of collections and arrays.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I thought it was obvious from the comments that there is no neat solution, so I dropped that part. Now I elaborated on this in the last paragraphs.

Comment: The abstraction described in the second half of this answer is unnecessary, because something equivalent already exists in the standard library. Just replace `Abstraction` with `Collection`, and `Abstraction.of(T[])` with `Arrays.asList`.

Comment: @David what would you replace `Abstraction` with for arrays of primitives?

Comment: `Abstraction` doesn't work on arrays of primitives because `T` has to be a subclass of `Object`. Change `new Integer[]` to `new int[]` and it fails to compile.

Comment: @JohnKugelman because it's an over-simplified abstraction ;) For instance, if you want to do it for `int[]`, you would need `IntConsumer` (not `Consumer <T>`) [it's another hierarchy to cover all consumer classes], `T` would represent an abstract type (not a direct type of the source) [it's another hierarchy to include [or wrap] all the primitive types). It's quite complicated, so I decided to drop it. It's going to be a decent piece of code (similar to ones mapping frameworks usually have)

Comment: @JohnKugelman I updated the answer with `IntArrayAbstraction` to help you see how primitive arrays can be integrated into this (simplified) abstraction...

Answer (score 6):

Depending on what you are trying to do, you might want to implement two similar methods:

```
public <T> void iterateOver(List<T> list) {
    // do whatever you want to do with your list
}

public <T> void iterateOver(T[] array) {
    this.iterateOver(Arrays.asList(array));
}
```

Or maybe even have an interface for this:

```
interface ExtendedIterableConsumer<T> {

    public void iterateOver(List<T> list);

    public default void iterateOver(T[] array) {
        this.iterateOver(Arrays.asList(array));

}
```

I am not sure if that helps you, because you seem to already have the object in question in a variable somewhere. But if you can address that problem one level higher, it might be useful.

Answer (score 5):

You can check if object is array by using `isArray()` method from `Class`

```
if (foo != null && (foo.getClass().isArray() || foo instanceof Collection<?>)){

}
```

Edit:

In terms of iterating over this `foo` object, there is no simple solution. However you could try something like this:

```
private void iterate(@NotNull Object foo) {
    if (foo instanceof Collection<?>) {
        for (Object o : ((Collection<?>) foo)) {
            chandleYourObject(o);
        }
    }

    if (foo.getClass().isArray()) {
        if (foo.getClass().isPrimitive()) {
            checkPrimitiveTypes(foo);
        }
        if (foo instanceof Object[]) {
            for (Object o : (Object[]) foo) {
                chandleYourObject(o);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void checkPrimitiveTypes(Object foo) {
    if (foo instanceof int[]) {
        for (int i : (int[]) foo) {

        }
    }
    //And the rest of primitive types
}

private void chandleYourObject(Object o ){
    //What you want to do with your object
}
```

Comment: you can just check if `foo instanceof Collection<?>`. Shorter and more clear in my opinion. No nee to use `Collection.class.isAssignableFrom`. I've added partial answer because at first you didn't include `isArray()` method in your answer :)

Comment: Though, I still believe that `Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(fooClass)` is more flexible than `foo instanceof Collection` because `Collection.class` could be any class at runtime (a dynamically obtained one, I mean)

Comment: Wouldn't that throw NPE when we would pass `int[] i = null`? I think that there will be no difference between `Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(fooClass)` and `foo instanceof Collection<?>`, that is just up to what you prefer and what is more readable for you ;)

Answer (score 4):

You could write a helper method for this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <E> void forEach(Object arrayOrIterable, Consumer<? super E> action) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(arrayOrIterable);
    if (arrayOrIterable instanceof Iterable) {
        for (Object o : (Iterable<?>) arrayOrIterable) {
            action.accept((E) o);
        }
    } else if (arrayOrIterable.getClass().isArray()) {
        int length = Array.getLength(arrayOrIterable);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            action.accept((E) Array.get(arrayOrIterable, i));
        }
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("not an array nor iterable: " + arrayOrIterable.getClass());
    }
}
```

The second branch makes use of the `java.reflect.Array` class which provides helper methods (may be slow), to get the `length` of an array and the element at a given index.

You may call it like this:

```
int[] ints = {1, 2, 3, 4};
forEach(ints, (Integer i) -> System.out.println(i));

List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
forEach(ints, (Integer i) -> System.out.println(i));
```

Due to the nature of generics, this method may throw a `ClassCastException`, e.g. this call:

```
int[] ints = {1, 2, 3, 4};
forEach(ints, (String s) -> System.out.println(s));
```

Would result in:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Comment: I wouldn't dare to name the parameter `arrayOrIterable` since it's an `Object` and it might be *anything*

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Well this method only works with an array or an iterable, and will throw an exception for every other `Object`, so this should help as documentation that really one of those two types is expected

Comment: oh, I get you. It's a matter of personal preference/style, I guess.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko It really is something that is purely opinion based, best would be of course an extensive java-doc stating what can be passed into this method, what exceptions may be thrown etc.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays are Objects:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html

AbstractCollections also extend Object:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html

So yes there is a common superclass, but unfortunately this isn't really going to help you.

I would suggest your best bet is to use:

```
List<> someList = Arrays.asList(sourceArray)
```

This will convert your array into a collection that implements Iterable.  You will of course need to work out if the initial object is an Array or a Collection in advance and only call the above if it is an array, here are some options for doing that:

```
boolean isArray = myArray.getClass().isArray();
boolean isCollection = Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(myList.getClass());
```

Comment: `Arrays.asList()` will sadly not work with primitive arrays

Comment: Agreed, but I'm making the assumption here that the OP is not using primitive arrays.  If they are they could do something like `Integer[] boxedInts = IntStream.of(ints).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);` (Assuming they aren't using a byte[] array, in which case it gets more complex)

Comment: `Arrays` is a utility class that "contains various methods for manipulating arrays". It is not the superclass of arrays.

Comment: True, updated the answer to point towards Java documentation that states Arrays are Objects instead,