# Does Map interface extend or implement some other interface or class?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, hashmap, frameworks

We know that Map interface does not implement Collection interface. Then what does Map implement or extend? Does it extend Object class directly?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html

Comment: Generally best to read the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html) by Oracle before posting on basic topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related question:
[Why doesn't Java Map extend Collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651819/why-doesnt-java-map-extend-collection)

[`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) does not extend any interfaces; it is defined as its own interface.

In Java, [interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(Java)) don't extend [classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html), only other interfaces. Technically, all objects in Java extend [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html), so any object implementing an interface is an [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html).